# How to get a parent components injector?

Tags: angular

If I have many components nested inside each other:

```
ComponentA
  |___ Component AA
  |___ Component AB
       |___ Component ABA
           |___ Component ABAA
  |___ Component AC
  |___ Component AD
```

and I am currently in the context of Component `ABAA`, how might I get the `Injector` for Component `AA`, or `A`?

Comment: For what do you need the injector ? If you have a service you can choose where to be injected (if you want a single instance for some components, or a new instance for other components) : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several ways to get the parent injector:

```
constructor(@SkipSelf() injector:Injector) {}
```

or

```
constructor(injector:Injector) {
  this.parentInjector = (injector as ReflectiveInjector).parent;
}
```

I don't know a way to get the injector of siblings of parents. I'm pretty sure there is a better way for the problem you actually try to resolve anyway.

Comment: I see. That's not the parent components injector. You can pass the injector to a shared service to make it available to others that inject that service. I'd strongly discourage passing injectors around though. To me this seems smelly. Can you elaborate what you actually try to accomplish?

Comment: Basically I just need to access a route outside of the components relative routes. I need to get access to the top level router. Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you need access to the top-level rooter you can just inject the `private router:Router` and access the root router like `this.router.root`. If the component can't inject a router because it's not a routed component then inject the router to a service and inject this service to the component to make the router available to it. If you provide this service at the top level, the injected router will already be the root router.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have the parent injector inside one of your factories you can use `SkipSelf` like this in your factory provider:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: MyService,
    useFactory: (parentInjector: Injector) => {
      // Create your service...
    },
    deps: [[new SkipSelf(), Injector]],
  },
],
```